# How to use tcpdump file to test syn flood attack?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, snort

I have a tcpdump file that will simulate a SYN flood attack. I have rules set up in SNORT that I would like to test on this tcpdump file. How would I go about running this on the command line? Or would this be a job for wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark only reads the data, to do something with the packets you captured you can create a python script using libpcap, read the packets and have your program work accordingly